# How to make the performance of query faster by using the things other than Union in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, union

I have an object called Product which have the attribute called ProductItem and tags.

```
public class Shop{
    public string Id {get; set;}
    public Product Products {get; set;}   
}

public class Product{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Id {get; set;}
    public Tag Tags {get; set;}
    public ProductItem ProductItems {get; set;}
    public Shop ShopInformation {get; set;}
}

public class Tag{
    public string Id {get; set;}
    public string name {get; set;}
}

public class ProductItem{
    public string Id {get; set;}
    public Tag Tags {get; set;}
}
```

I would like to get all the tags in both Products and Tags from the datacontext 
and I use this query

```
var result = from shop in dataContext.Shop
             select new Response
             {
                 Id = shop.Id,
                 Tags = (from product in dataContext.Product
                 where product.ShopInformation.Id == shop.Id
                 from productTag in 
                 product.Tags.Union(product.ProductItems.SelectMany(s => s.Tags))
                 select productTag.Name).Distinct(),
             };
```

However, the performance is pretty slow, and thus I would like to know if there is a way to collect all tags faster.

Comment: What does the generated SQL query look like? Did you take a peek at the execution plan?

Comment: productItems are innerjoin to the product and union all with all the skus in the product. The process is repeated for all the shops